# How to trade NULL value from a column for last non-NULL value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I'm implementing a query that should work no SQLite and PostgreSQL. My database have 2 tables that I want to order by date, interpolating the values of sensors. My tables ares de following:

Valor_Sensor_Pressão:

```
ID_Sensor_Pressão |    Data_Medição    | Valor_Medido
1                  2016-01-01 10:20:05   13
1                  2016-01-01 10:20:06   11
1                  2016-01-01 10:20:12   20
1                  2016-01-01 10:20:13   0
1                  2016-01-01 10:21:05   100
```

Valor_Sensor_Temperatura:

```
ID_Sensor_Temperatura |    Data_Medição    | Valor_Medido
1                      2016-01-01 10:20:05   1
1                      2016-01-01 10:20:08   3
1                      2016-01-01 10:20:12   20
1                      2016-01-01 10:21:05   1
1                      2016-01-01 10:21:13   31
```

I've made the following SQL to aggregate and interpolate the data by dates:

```sql
WITH Resultado (ValorPressão, ValorTemperatura, DataMedida) AS (
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p
        LEFT JOIN Valor_Sensor_Temperatura AS t USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE p.ID_Sensor_Pressão = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Temperatura AS t
        LEFT JOIN Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE
        p.Data_Medição IS NULL
        AND t.ID_Sensor_Temperatura = 1
    ORDER BY COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição)
)

SELECT DataMedida, ValorPressão, ValorTemperatura FROM Resultado
```

The result are the following:

```
"2016-01-01 10:20:05"   "13"    "1"
"2016-01-01 10:20:06"   "11"    NULL
"2016-01-01 10:20:08"   NULL    "3"
"2016-01-01 10:20:12"   "20"    "20"
"2016-01-01 10:20:13"   "0"     NULL
"2016-01-01 10:21:05"   "100"   "1"
"2016-01-01 10:21:13"   NULL    "31"
```

I've read the following [page](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/) and adapted a solution to a query that would be used in SQLite and PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH Resultado (ValorPressão, ValorTemperatura, DataMedida) AS (
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p
        left join Valor_Sensor_Temperatura t USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE p.ID_Sensor_Pressão = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Temperatura AS t
        LEFT JOIN Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE
        p.Data_Medição IS NULL
        AND t.ID_Sensor_Temperatura = 1
    ORDER BY COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição)
)

SELECT
    DataMedida,
    COALESCE(last_value(ValorPressão) OVER (order by DataMedida), 0) AS ValorPressão,
    COALESCE(last_value(ValorTemperatura) over (order by DataMedida), 0) AS ValorTemperatura
FROM Resultado
```

I couldn't figure out what is the error, because the LAST_VALUE didn't give me the previous row value, so COALESCE put 0 instead the previous value, and I couldn't find a substitute to IGNORE NULLS for SQLite.

What modifications will return the previous value of a column instead of NULL? Giving me something like this:

```
"2016-01-01 10:20:05"   "13"    "1"
"2016-01-01 10:20:06"   "11"    "1"
"2016-01-01 10:20:08"   "11"    "3"
"2016-01-01 10:20:12"   "20"    "20"
"2016-01-01 10:20:13"   "0"     "20"
"2016-01-01 10:21:05"   "100"   "1"
"2016-01-01 10:21:13"   "100    "31"
```

EDIT: The IDs I will get from others table, so I put the WHERE selecting "1" just to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure out the problem, I was making a mistake with LAG and LAST_VALUE. The solution was to merge the two inside the last COALESCE and adding FIRST_VALUE.

I added a new row in "Valor_Sensor_Pressão" to check when I got a NULL at the first row:

```
"1" "2016-01-01 10:20:00"   "5.5"
```

So my final query is:

```
WITH Resultado (ValorPressão, ValorTemperatura, DataMedida) AS (
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p
        LEFT JOIN Valor_Sensor_Temperatura t USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE p.ID_Sensor_Pressão = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.Valor_Medido AS pValue,
        t.Valor_Medido AS tValue,
        COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição) AS DataMedida
    FROM Valor_Sensor_Temperatura AS t
        LEFT JOIN Valor_Sensor_Pressão AS p USING (Data_Medição)
    WHERE
        p.Data_Medição IS NULL
        AND t.ID_Sensor_Temperatura = 1
    ORDER BY COALESCE(p.Data_Medição, t.Data_Medição)
)

SELECT
    DataMedida,
    COALESCE(LAST_VALUE(ValorPressão) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida),LAG(ValorPressão) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida), FIRST_VALUE(ValorPressão) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida),0) AS ValorPressão,
    COALESCE(LAST_VALUE(ValorTemperatura) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida), LAG(ValorTemperatura) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida), FIRST_VALUE(ValorTemperatura) OVER (ORDER BY DataMedida),0) AS ValorTemperatura
FROM Resultado
```

And my result is:

```
"2016-01-01 10:20:00"   "5.5"   "0"
"2016-01-01 10:20:05"   "13"    "1"
"2016-01-01 10:20:06"   "11"    "1"
"2016-01-01 10:20:08"   "11"    "3"
"2016-01-01 10:20:12"   "20"    "20"
"2016-01-01 10:20:13"   "0"     "20"
"2016-01-01 10:21:05"   "100"   "1"
"2016-01-01 10:21:13"   "100"   "31"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your current query more easily as:

```
select id, data, Valor_Medido, valor_temperatura
from (select ID_Sensor_Pressã as id, Data_Medição as data, Valor_Medido, null as valor_temperatura
      from valor_Sensor_Pressão
      union all
      select ID_Sensor_Temperatura, Data_Medição, null, Valor_Medido
      from Valor_Sensor_Temperatura
     ) v
group by id, data;
```

Then, what you want to do is more easily done in Postgres using window functions.  But for a general solution, you can use subqueries:

```
with v as (
      select id, data, max(Valor_Medido) as Valor_Medido, max(valor_temperatura) as valor_temperatura
      from (select ID_Sensor_Pressã as id, Data_Medição as data, Valor_Medido, null as valor_temperatura
            from valor_Sensor_Pressão
            union all
            select ID_Sensor_Temperatura, Data_Medição, null, Valor_Medido
            from Valor_Sensor_Temperatura
           ) v
      group by id, data
     )
select v.*,
       coalesce(Valor_Medido,
                (select v2.Valor_Medido
                 from v v2
                 where v2.id = v.id and v2.data < v.data
                 order by v2.data desc
                 limit 1
                )
               ) as valor_medido,
       coalesce(valor_temperatura,
                (select v2.valor_temperatura
                 from v v2
                 where v2.id = v.id and v2.data < v.data
                 order by v2.data desc
                 limit 1
                )
               ) as valor_temperatura,
from v;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I've removed the ID part, because it will come from others tables. But, when I try the first query the result isn't the same that I want first. Moreover, an error occur saying that there is syntax error after the last "FROM", what doesn't make sense, because you defined "v". I will keep trying following your suggestion.